# Finding groups of clusters in binary array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, cluster-analysis

I have a binary image which I have extracted all the pixels and wrote them to a txt file.  I am trying to find how many clusters and where there are clusters of 25 or more 1's in the array.

DBSCAN, euclidean distances.

```
db_scan = DBSCAN(eps=1, min_samples=25,metric='euclidean', metric_params=None, algorithm='auto').fit(im_bw)
```

I expect to find the i, j location of the center of the clusters.  I expect to find the number of clusters but says i only have 1

Answer (score 0):

It probably says 0 clusters, only *noise*.

Because in a radius of 1 pixel you won't have 25 pixels.

Note that you need to make sure you chose the right representation and don't make false assumptions on what the algorithm does... For example, it does not produce centers.